# анимация движения нескольких объектов

Tags: android

Есть идея сделать анимацию движения гонщиков по трассе. Саму трассу отрисовал в CustomView. Если правильно понимаю - теперь необходимо для гонщиков в отдельном потоке выводить анимацию движения (для каждого в отдельном потоке). Но непонятно как потоки цеплять к имеющемуся отображению трассы, да и правильно ли так реализовывать вообще.

Может есть другие варианты реалиации.

Код вывода трассы (Италия Монца):

```
public class RaceTrackView extends View {

private Paint paint;
private Path ptCurve = new Path(); //curve

private int screenWidth;
private int screenHeight;
private float scalingFactor;

private float[][] pointsMap;
List<PointF> aPoints;

public RaceTrackView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
}

public RaceTrackView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    init();
}

public RaceTrackView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    init();
}

private void init(){
    getWindowSize(getContext());

    pointsMap = generatePointsMap();

    getScalingFactor(getMaxX(), getMaxY());

    aPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    getPoints(aPoints);

    initCurve();
    getPaint();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(ptCurve, paint);
}

private float[][] generatePointsMap(){
    // точки трассы
    return new float[][]{{307,250},{160,236},{153,224},{128,235},{82,231},{70,225},{43,199},{33,176},
            {31,130},{32,96},{20,87},{23,73},{2,31},{7,10},{73,3},{106,76},{194,168},{213,169},{225,174},
            {237,189},{424,203},{436,219},{429,242},{406,255},{307,250},{300,249}};
}

private float getMaxX(){
    float tmpMax = 0f;

    for (float[] floats : pointsMap) {
        if (floats[0] > tmpMax)
            tmpMax = floats[0];
    }

    return tmpMax;
}

private float getMaxY(){
    float tmpMax = 0f;

    for (float[] floats : pointsMap) {
        if (floats[1] > tmpMax)
            tmpMax = floats[1];
    }

    return tmpMax;
}

private void getPoints(List<PointF> points){
    float horizontalPadding = (screenWidth - getMaxX() * scalingFactor)/2;
    int topPaddingMap = 50;

    for (float[] aPointsMap : pointsMap) {
        points.add(new PointF(
                aPointsMap[0] * scalingFactor + horizontalPadding,
                aPointsMap[1] * scalingFactor + topPaddingMap
        ));
    }
}

private void getWindowSize(Context context){
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
}

private void getScalingFactor(float maxX, float maxY){
    // масштабирование под размер экрана
    scalingFactor = (((float)screenWidth - 50)/maxX > ((float)screenHeight - 300)/maxY)
            ? ((float)screenHeight - 300)/maxY
            : ((float)screenWidth - 50)/maxX;
}

private void getPaint(){
    //init paint object
    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(13);
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 148, 255));
}

private void initCurve(){
    //init smooth curve
    PointF point = aPoints.get(0);
    ptCurve.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
    for(int i = 0; i < aPoints.size() - 1; i++){
        point = aPoints.get(i);
        PointF next = aPoints.get(i+1);
        ptCurve.quadTo(point.x, point.y, (next.x + point.x) / 2, (point.y + next.y) / 2);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочешь дергать объекты из отдельного треда, то тебе только одна дорога - СюрфейсВью, так как все остальные вьюшки надо дергать из основного треда. Вот внутри этого сюрфейса и рисуй все вместе, целиком.